# azure devop build pipeline not triggering

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

This is my yaml:

```
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
     - master
     - R_current_Sprint
 paths:
   exclude:
      - YAML/*

extends:
  template: ThunderPipeline.yaml
  parameters:
      MergeBetweenBranches: false
```

But when I merged somthing to R_current_Sprint today, somehow the build pipeline is not triggered.

However, if I overwrite what is available in yaml with this and do another merge to R_current_Sprint. The pipeline is triggered. So indeed something not right.

Is there a log or something to see why the pipeline is not triggered by my yaml file?

[image]

Comment: strange...it is behaving just opposite for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The branch names in yaml trigger are **case sensitive**!

It should be `R_Current_Sprint` instead of `R_current_Sprint`:

```
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
     - master
     - R_Current_Sprint
 paths:
   exclude:
      - YAML/*
```

The trigger in Yaml can not work cause you're using `R_current_Sprint`. The reason why the GUI setting works is that you use the correct `R_Current_Sprint`.

Just correct the branch name in your yaml file, and this issue would go away.